# How to implement getXAttribute on a class that is not a Model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom class that does a request getItems() to NAV server and returns an array. I'm able to collect($array) and use all collection functions, such as groupBy, where, but I can't seem to find a way to make the $appends work. 
For example I want this class to have a

```php
public function getPriceAttribute(){
  return $this->customCollection->Unit_Price*100 . 'Euro';
}
```

All the documents I find online are about Models. I know it's a Model thingy, but would be awesome to make it work without the database table, since all the data comes from a NavClient

Thank you

Comment: Not following. When you say "make it work without the database table" what do you mean? What does this custom class have to do with that? Confused. Maybe share some code.

Comment: The answer is exactly what I was looking for. I'll edit my answer as soon as possible to provide some further code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is coded in the `Model` class so it's probably not possible to easily use it for non-models. Instead you could copy the relevant code to your class.

Laravel uses the [`__get()` magic function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) in the [Model class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1521). Then in the `HasAttributes` trait it [checks for the existence of an mutator method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/31eee296690a1ecb51a8d14046ff1e13a9d236d6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L438) and then [calls the mutator](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/31eee296690a1ecb51a8d14046ff1e13a9d236d6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L450).

```php
    public function hasGetMutator($key)
    {
        return method_exists($this, 'get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute');
    }

    protected function mutateAttribute($key, $value = null)
    {
        return $this->{'get'.Str::studly($key).'Attribute'}($value);
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
        if($this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
            return $this->mutateAttribute($key);
        }
    }
```

Note: The `__get()` method will only be called if there is no public property with the requested name (in your case `price`).

**Update:** There is [a Laravel Core Adventures video](https://laravelcoreadventures.com/the-lost-eloquent-temple-of-doom/level/6) that goes into more detail.